# RStudio pipe operator (%>%) shortcut (CTRL+SHIFT+M) not working in Edge browser

Tags: pipe, tidyverse, microsoft-edge, rstudio-server

I encountered a number of situation where my pipe operator shortcut (%>%) was not working in RStudio Server in my Microsoft Edge browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was that the shortkey (CTRL+SHIFT+M) is assigned to something else in Microsoft Edge, namely to the function to 'Sign in as a different user or browse as a Guest'.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-edge-50d3edab-30d9-c7e4-21ce-37fe2713cfad

According to a Microsoft forum there is no way to change the pre-defined Edge shortcuts. End of story. At least this is clear; but doesn't make a me a happy user.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. You can mark it as accepted after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The allocate the same shortcut to mute in Teams if I recall correctly...

You could allocate %>% to a different shortcut I believe. Although I've never been convinced it was a major typing task...

Comment: The shortkey is a habbit that is in your system so....